# How to build a core bot in efficient clean code and less verbose

Tags: python

I am writing a bot which checks the first word and process an action under the if statement.
so all my code are with **a lot** if-statements like that:

```
if(len(text) >= len("foo") and key[:len("foo")].lower() == "foo")
```

and only "foo" text is changed to the required first word.

Is it possible to make it less verbose, and more cleaner?
each action is pretty similar - I'm creating an object with relevant arguments and send it back.

I thought somehow to box the action for each if statement and save it under dictionary which the value is a boolean function, isFoo() for example, is it will be more cleaner? or even more verbose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startswith` string method like this:

```
lower_text = text.lower()
if lower_text.startswith("foo"):
    ... YOUR CODE HERE ...
```

Documentation for [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Comment: but it could match also foo*, i.e 'foofoo', 'fooabc', 'foo ', sometimes it just one word so I can't startwith "foo ". and sometimes it couple words after foo.

Comment: Then combine it with     word = text.split(maxsplit=1)[0]

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a lot cleaner if you create boolean functions which contain this check logic.